# Как поменять цвет заголовка и цвет нижней линии во вкладках?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

В моем приложении реализованы вкладки с помощью TabHost и TabWidget. Как можно изменить цвет заголовков и  цвет нижних линий(TabStrip)?
И вообще,есть более глобальный вопрос: в некоторых примерах вкладки реализованы через TabLayout. Какая разница между моей реализацией и TabLayout? Что лучше использовать?

tab_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_main_background">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

фрагмент, где создаются вкладки:

```
public class TradescreenViewpager1FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vpager1_1st_fragment, container, false);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("BUY BTC");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("SELL BTC");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Я пробовал добавлять собственный стиль в файл styles.xml. Меняется цвет полностью всей вкладки, а мне не нужно менять цвет фона.

UPD:
Сейчас переделал под TabLayout, контент добавляю в с помощью xml. Но приложение падает.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorGrey"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorGreen"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/color_main"
            android:text="BUY BTC">
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout). И вот ответ для него:

Если нету импорта у родителя - делаем

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Дальше параметры думаю понятны:

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/about_tab"
app:tabTextColor="@color/about_tab"
```

Comment: Пробую добавить TabLayout вместо TabHost, и приложение падает. Контент во вкладки добавляю с помощью TabItem. что не так?

Comment: Необходим адаптер. Можете тут посмотреть как реализовать http://www.fandroid.info/kak-sozdat-vkladki-tablayout-v-stile-material-design/

Comment: Цвета поменял. А как можно еще изменить размер шрифта?

Comment: @Snuf, сначала нужно добавить стиль 
`<style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>`

А потом указать этот стиль в виджете 'TabLayout':
`app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"`